# Function calls within InfoWindows

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, onclick, infowindow

Often I have maps with a whole lot of markers (let's say representing shops). I have infowindows that display basic info on the shop represented by the marker, then, on the infoWindow HTML I like to put a button that, for example, says "Details".
The html of the infowindow is simple.. the html of the info window would include an

```
input type="button" value="Show More" onclick="showMore(' + shopId + ');
```

The relevant shopId would be obviously different for every marker...

The problem is that the showMore function has to be declared as a global function to the javascript otherwise the infowindow doesn't find it.

Lets say that all the code (generating map, placing markers, declaring infowindows, etc) is in a function called `function showShops() {}` , and the `showMore(id)` function is inside the showShops() function, HOw can I tell the "onclick" event to call the showMore() function inside the showShops function?

Just to check my code, I've changed it to `onclick="alert(' + shopId + ')` .. and I correctly get an alert with the relevant shop id..

Answer (score 6):

The content of a infowindow may either be a string or a **node**.

To achieve it you must use a node that will be created inside the scope of `showShops()`

Sample-creation of such a node:

```
var content = document.createElement('div');
content.innerHTML = 'some text<br/>';

var button = content.appendChild(document.createElement('input'));
button.type = 'button';
button.value = 'click me!';

google.maps.event.addDomListener(button,'click', function(){showMore(id)});
```

Simple Demo: [**http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/8ZsSp/**](http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/8ZsSp/)

Comment: Very cool.  Didn't know GMaps let's you use nodes instead of strings.  Learned something new.  Thanks!